# Intellij 13.1.4 not finding resources when rendering

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have an android project that seemingly can't see some resources during rendering.

In AndroidManifest.xml: 
`android:label="@string/app_name"` doesn't resolve.

In the task.xml layout:
`android:text="@string/Edit"` doesn't resolve

(16 other similar errors not shown)

Perhaps surprisingly the project builds successfully.  It is only when I attempt to render a layout that I see these issues.

These issues all congregate around:

```
res/values/meas.xml
res/values/strings.xml
```

This project has not been under development for approximately one year. Did something change that I'm not aware of?

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is **clearly a Intellij 13.1.4 issue!**

When I switched over to **Intellij 14.?  - Build #IU-138.1503, built on August 7, 2014**
**all works as expected.**

I hope this helps someone else.